# Get UTC time and format it without milliseconds

Tags: java, scala, datetime

I have the following function that returns a `DateTime` format which I can easily print using the `toString` method.

```
def getUTCNow(): DateTime = {
    val now = new Date()
    val utc = new DateTime(now).withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC)
    utc
  }
```

However, it prints something like `2016-09-24T00:07:40.446Z` which is what I want but without the `.446` milliseconds character. How do I get that?

My end result should look like this: `2016-09-24T00:07:40Z`

Comment: Which DateTime is that? Joda's? If so, it has a toString that accepts a pattern string, you seem to be looking for `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ`

Comment: @fvu: Thank you. that works! I had to make a change to the `ZZ` to `'Z'` just to match my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using java and joda , this can be done as follows

```
DateTime dateTime =  new DateTime(new Date()).withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC);
System.out.println(dateTime.toString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"));
```

In your case as well the equivalent should be similar to :

```
utc.toString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
```

prints : `2016-09-24T02:22:15Z`